# How to fix 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined' error in Prestashop Module

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop

I am having a problem with a Prestashop module and the developer does not respond to help me. Will anyone know how to tell me why I receive the following error in the console? Thanks!!!

```
admin.js:57 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at updateShortcodeTags (admin.js:57)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (admin.js:72)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2)
```

This is the admin.js file: https://codeshare.io/5ZBEAd

Comment: `metaInputVal = $("#"+inputId).val();` is giving you an undefined value. That's all the help we can provide

Comment: Looks like when the code link 72 is run for "cmstitlemeta" this is not defined in the window object you are running in so cannot be read, i would check input with the id="cmstitlemedai" exists on the page

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this type of error, check if value exists before try to acess to property of functions :

```js
    updateShortcodeTags = function(inputId){
        metaInputVal = $("#"+inputId).val();
        if(!metaInputVal) return; //add this one
        metaInputVal = metaInputVal.split('-');
        $("#"+inputId+"-tags").empty();
        $("select[data-metainput='"+inputId+"'] option").removeAttr("disabled").css('color','#000');
        for(i = 0; i < metaInputVal.length; i++){
            // console.log();
            metaInputVal[i] = metaInputVal[i].trim();
            $("select[data-metainput='"+inputId+"'] option[Value='" + metaInputVal[i] + "']").prop("disabled","disabled").css('color','#eee');
            if(metaInputVal[i] != ''){
                $("#"+inputId+"-tags").append('<span class="badge" style="margin:2px;">'+metaInputVal[i]+'<span class="btn" style="padding:0 0 0 5px;"><b data-metainput="'+inputId+'" data-removed="'+metaInputVal[i]+'" onclick="removeThisShortcode($(this));" style="font-family:arial;">x</b></span></span>');
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

downgrade your php version to 7.2 or 7.3

Comment: How does that help with this JavaScript error?

Comment: I don't know - but its help.